# Does A Function Always Return A Value

Tags: javascript, function, console, undefined, return-value

I have been reading a bit about `undefined` and just started wondering that we see `undefined` when we declare a function in browser console.

Does calling a function always return a value? If we do not explicitly `return` a value, then by default `undefined` value is returned from a function.

That is to say, a function will always return a value. Always. Is that correct?

```
var aFunc = function(){
 console.log( "aFunc ran." );
}
aFunc() === undefined // true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it always returns a value, if explicit one is not given, it returns `undefined`. This is same as you will write `return undefined` or just `return`.